# Getting gps data from any device using python

Tags: android, python, gps

I want to write a python script. This script will run on windows machine and read the GPS data from nearby GPS receivers (eg. Android phone). I don't want to run the script in those devices. My script should run on the windows machine and locate the nearby devices and get the GPS data from those devices. Is it possible? If possible, can anyone please explain the way to achieve this?

Comment: Android devices won't provide you their GPS data just because you want it. You will have to write an Android app, which will provide you with that data. Also you have to decide how you want to pass that data from Android devices to your PC. Using which channel?

Comment: I want to transfer the data using bluetooth socket

Comment: ok, then `You will have to write an Android app, which will provide you with that data.` still

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks :)